# How to set the space between the \int with its superscript?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

`MdSymbol` is an excellent sans math (just symbol) font macro package

I think `\int` with its superscript are too tight, how to set the space between the `\int` with its superscript?

[image]

here a example, please use it

```
\documentclass[10pt,utf8]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage{mdsymbol}
\newcommand*\uppi\pi

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
     \int_{-\frac{\uppi}2}^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\sin^4 x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&{} = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\sin^4 x}\,\mathrm{d}x
    = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\cos^2 x}{1+\cos^4 x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&{} = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^4 x + 1}\,\mathrm{d}x
    = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\mathrm{d}(\tan x)}{(1+\tan^2 x)^2 + 1}\\
(\tan x \wedgeq u)\quad
&{} = 2\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t^2)^2 + 1}
    = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t^2)^2 + 1}\\
\Bigl(t \wedgeq \frac1u\Bigr)\quad
&{} = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2 + \frac1{2u^2}+1}
    = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\bigl(u-\frac1{u\sqrt{2}}\bigr)^2 + (\sqrt{2}+1)}\\
&{} = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2 + (\sqrt{2}+1)}
    = \frac{\uppi}{2\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}} = \frac{\uppi}{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}.
\end{align*}
It's using follow $\int^0 \dotsi \int^\infty \dotsi \int^d \dotsi \int^g$\quad%
$\displaystyle \int^0 \dotsi \int^\infty \dotsi \int^d \dotsi \int^g$
\[
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\Bigl(x-\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)\,\mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, \quad
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2 + \alpha^2}
= \frac{\uppi}{\alpha}\quad (a>0,\alpha>0).
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: Do replace all 5 instances of `&{} =` with `&=`. If nothing else, this change will help cut down on code clutter.

Comment: tks, sometime will make a difference between the two methods, the difference  is that adding ```{}``` can ensure ```=``` be a binary relational symbol, without ```{}```, the spacing of ```=``` two sides maybe not equal... I don’t know for sure if it ’s true. It became my habit..

Comment: That is true for the right-aligned columns, and you indeed need `={}&`. Left-aligned columns always start with an empty group.

Comment: Just by the way you wrote `\tan x \wedgeq u` but you made the substitution tan(*x*) ↦ *t*.

Comment: @gen-z-ready-to-perish Tks for correct, I have selected examples with more ```\int``` from my document, without double checking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `e` argument specifier of `xparse` to scan and see whether subscripts or superscripts come along. If they do, add `\,` to superscripts and `\!` to subscripts.

This happens by adding `\fixlimits` at the end of the working of `\int`. You may want to do similarly to other integral types, with a similar `\xapptocmd` line for each.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts}
\usepackage{mdsymbol}
\usepackage{xparse,xpatch}

\newcommand{\uppi}{\pi}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fixlimits}{e{^_}}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{^{\,#1}}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{_{\!#2}}%
}
\xapptocmd{\int}{\fixlimits}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
     \int_{-\frac{\uppi}2}^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\sin^4 x}\diff x
&{} = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\sin^4 x}\diff x
    = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\cos^2 x}{1+\cos^4 x}\diff x\\
&{} = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^4 x + 1}\diff x
    = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\diff (\tan x)}{(1+\tan^2 x)^2 + 1}\\
(\tan x \wedgeq u)\quad
&{} = 2\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\diff t}{(1+t^2)^2 + 1}
    = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\diff t}{(1+t^2)^2 + 1}\\
\Bigl(t \wedgeq \frac1u\Bigr)\quad
&{} = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\diff u}{u^2 + \frac1{2u^2}+1}
    = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\diff u}{\bigl(u-\frac1{u\sqrt{2}}\bigr)^2 + (\sqrt{2}+1)}\\
&{} = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\diff u}{u^2 + (\sqrt{2}+1)}
    = \frac{\uppi}{2\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}} = \frac{\uppi}{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}.
\end{align*}
It's using follow $\int^0 \dotsi \int^\infty \dotsi \int^d \dotsi \int^g$\quad%
$\displaystyle \int^0 \dotsi \int^\infty \dotsi \int^d \dotsi \int^g$
\[
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\Bigl(x-\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)\diff x
= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\diff x, \quad
  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\diff x}{x^2 + \alpha^2}
= \frac{\uppi}{\alpha}\quad (a>0,\alpha>0).
\]

\end{document}
```

In the meantime, I changed all explicit `\mathrm{d}` so when you will eventually return in the world of mathematicians you'll be able to make your d's italic by simply changing one line. `;-)`

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the answer I desire, simple and general, and thank you for your ```\diff```, I completely forgot the trouble this ```d``` caused me

Comment: One more detail, In text mode, this spacing seems wider, how to set ```\displaystyle``` and ```\textstyle``` separately?

Comment: @poorich That's ***much*** more complicated.

Comment: ```{^{\:#1}}``` -> ```{^{\if (in displaystyle) {\,} \else {length2}\fi}#1}}``` is this feasible? Don't know how to express ```(in displaystyle)```

Comment: @poorich No, it doesn't work like that. You need to scan the current style in advance and this requires an extensive change in the definition of `\int`.

Comment: Just be the way you wrote `\tan x \wedgeq u` but you made the substitution tan(*x*) ↦ *t*

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Ask the OP. I just used the given code and did not check the math.

Comment: Done. ⠀ ⠀ ⠀ ⠀ ⠀

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you can use LuaLaTeX, it's straightforward to apply some spacing adjustments "on the fly", *before* TeX starts its usual processing.

The working assumption in the following, LuaLaTeX-based solution is that the lower and upper limits of integration either consist of a single letter or digit or are encased in curly braces. Thus, `\int_0^1` can be processed, whereas `\int^\infty` cannot. (You would need to write `\int^{\infty}` -- which is probably good practice anyway.) It's also assumed that the lower limit is always entered before the upper limit. Finally, it's ok to have an integral with just an upper limit.

The code below shifts the lower limit to the left (by `2mu`) and shifts the upper limit to the right (also by `2mu`); feel free to adjust the shift amounts. Oh, `3mu` is equivalent to 1 unit of thinspace (=`1/6em`).

The Lua function is activated by running `\AdjustIntSpacingOn`. If you ever need to deactivate it, just run `\AdjustIntSpacingOff`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{sansmathfonts,mdsymbol}
\let\uppi\pi

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function int_spacing ( s )
  s = s:gsub ( "\\int%s-_%s-(%b{})%s-^%s-(%b{})" , "\\int_{\\mkern-2mu%1}^{\\mkern2mu%2}" ) 
  s = s:gsub ( "\\int%s-_%s-(%w)%s-^%s-(%b{})" , "\\int_{\\mkern-2mu%1}^{\\mkern2mu%2}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "\\int%s-_%s-(%w)%s-^%s-(%w)" , "\\int_{\\mkern-2mu%1}^{\\mkern2mu%2}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "\\int%s-^%s-(%b{})"          , "\\int^{\\mkern2mu%1}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "\\int%s-^%s-(%w)"            , "\\int^{\\mkern2mu%1}" )
  return s
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\AdjustIntSpacingOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", int_spacing, "int_spacing")}}
\newcommand\AdjustIntSpacingOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback(
   "process_input_buffer", "int_spacing")}}
\AtBeginDocument{\AdjustIntSpacingOn}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\frac{\uppi}2}^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\sin^4 x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&= 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sin^2 x}{1+\sin^4 x}\,\mathrm{d}x
    = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\cos^2 x}{1+\cos^4 x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^4 x + 1}\,\mathrm{d}x
    = 2\int_0^{\frac{\uppi}2} \frac{\mathrm{d}(\tan x)}{(1+\tan^2 x)^2 + 1}\\
(\tan x \wedgeq u)\quad
&= 2\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t^2)^2 + 1}
    = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(1+t^2)^2 + 1}\\
\Bigl(t \wedgeq \frac1u\Bigr)\quad
&= \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2 + \frac1{2u^2}+1}
    = \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\bigl(u-\frac1{u\sqrt{2}}\bigr)^2 + (\sqrt{2}+1)}\\
&= \frac12\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2 + (\sqrt{2}+1)}
    = \frac{\uppi}{2\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}} = \frac{\uppi}{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}\,.
\end{align*}
It's using
$\int_0^1 \dotsi \int{^\infty} \dotsi \int^d \dotsi \int^g$\quad
$\displaystyle 
 \int_0^1 \dotsi \int^{\infty} \dotsi \int^d \dotsi \int^g$
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f\Bigl(x-\frac{a}{x}\Bigr)\,\mathrm{d}x
  = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, \quad
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2 + \alpha^2}
  = \frac{\uppi}{\alpha}\quad (a>0,\alpha>0)\,.
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I did not expect \int^{\infty} being different from \int^\infty.